# Split text into variables based on pattern c#

Tags: c#, split

I have this form of text string

```
<remittance><contain><blrn>032398106/17/59321</blrn><brmt>17GR0900FG344</brmt><bamnt>0</bamnt><bmsv>120,00</bmsv></contain></remittance>
```

Is there a way to get every node into variables so I can use them individual as variables in my form?

I want something like this

```
blrn = "032398106/17/59321"
brmt = "17GR0900FG344"
bamnt = "0"
bmsv = "120,00"
```

Itried a code like this

```
    string data = "&lt;remittance&gt;&lt;contain&gt;&lt;blrn&gt;032398106/17/59321&lt;/blrn&gt;&lt;brmt&gt;lrn /afm check error&lt;/brmt&gt;&lt;bamnt&gt;0&lt;/bamnt&gt;&lt;bmsv&gt;0&lt;/bmsv&gt;&lt;/contain&gt;&lt;/remittance&gt;";
    var decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data);

    string[] export;
    export = decoded.Replace("<blrn>", "|").Split('|');
```

but it doesnt return the corect values to export

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This text is essentially an Xml Document.  You can get the content this way:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml(yourxmlstring);
System.Xml.XmlElement root = xd.DocumentElement;
System.Xml.XmlNodeList nl = root.SelectNodes("//remittance/contain");
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xnode in nl.Item(0).ChildNodes)
{
    string name = xnode.Name;
    string value = xnode.InnerText;
    dictionary.Add(name, value);
    }
```

Comment: i had to change it a bit...the node list (nl) will contain your contain node...then nl.item[0].ChildNodes will be the nodes you need.

Comment: @Ctzkane525 the nl.Item[0] gives me an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'"

Comment: Sorry it's (0)...it's a method

Comment: Thanks. It's working great. Can you tell me if and how can I return this dictionary to my other form which I call this method? I want to use those values to a report

Comment: Create a function that inputs your string and returns dictionary<string, string>.  Your last line will be return dictionary;

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thanks a lot